# Load a C++ DLL in .exe application

Tags: c++, dll, static, load, exe

it is possible to load a DLL created in C ++ at compile time. in fact, the goal is to distribute only the .exe without the .dll ?

Thank you .

Comment: It is. It's called static linking.

Comment: Short answer: no, build a staic library not a DLL.  Medium answer: use an installer to install both. Long answer: it is possible to include the DLL as a resource in your application, extract it when your application runs and then dynamically load it.

Comment: The term at `compile-time` is incorrect. You can `link` either `statically` or `dynamically`. So the thing is about linking not compiling.

Comment: You could create an installer for your application. I use NSIS for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to allow distribution of the stand-alone executable as a single file, you could achieve that by using the following method:

- Compile the dll you want to include
- Serialize it into a binary string and hard code it into your application
- When your application starts, open a file and write the `DLL` string into it using binary mode
- Load the DLL using `LoadLibrary()` and use it